# unit of measurement for moveit plan

Tags: moveit

Hi can someone help me to find out what the unit of measuremnt of the distance variable in this code is? I'm using it to control a ur10:

```
//-------------- Längenberechnung der Trajectorie-----------------------------------------
double calculateDistance(const std::vector<double>& p1, const std::vector<double>& p2)
{
   if (p1.size() != p2.size())
   {
       RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("EndEffectorIkSolverNode"), "Gelenkpunkt-Dimensionen stimmen nicht überein");
       return 0.0;
   }

   double distance = 0.0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < p1.size(); ++i)
   {
       distance += std::abs(p1[i] - p2[i]);
   }
   return distance;
} 


//------------Callabkc wenn eine PSoe erhalten worden ist--------------------------------

void poseCallback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Point::SharedPtr msg,
                 moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface& move_group_interface,
                 rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Bool>::SharedPtr planningResultPub,
                 rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Bool>::SharedPtr executionResultPub,
                 rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float64>::SharedPtr planningTimePub,
                 rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float64>::SharedPtr executionTimePub,
                 rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float64>::SharedPtr planningAttPub,
                 rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float64>::SharedPtr planLenPub) {

   // Setzen der Zeilpose
   geometry_msgs::msg::Pose target_pose;
   target_pose.position.x = msg->x;
   target_pose.position.y = msg->y;
   target_pose.position.z = msg->z;

   // setzen der Orientierung für "wrist_3_link" mittels quaternion
   tf2::Quaternion quaternion;
   quaternion.setRPY(M_PI, 0.0, -M_PI_2); 
   target_pose.orientation.x = quaternion.getX();
   target_pose.orientation.y = quaternion.getY();
   target_pose.orientation.z = quaternion.getZ();
   target_pose.orientation.w = quaternion.getW();

   move_group_interface.setPoseTarget(target_pose);


   // planen einer trajectorie
   bool success = false;
   moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;

   const int max_attempts = 10; // Maximalanzahl an Plaungsversuchen

   for (int attempt = 0; attempt < max_attempts && !success; ++attempt) {
     RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("EndEffectorIkSolverNode"), "Planung gescheitert Versuch: %d", attempt);   
     std::tie(success, plan) = [&move_group_interface]() -> std::pair<bool, moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan> {
         moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan msg;
         auto const ok = static_cast<bool>(move_group_interface.plan(msg));
         return std::make_pair(ok, msg);
     }();

     if (!success) {
       RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("EndEffectorIkSolverNode"), "Planung gescheitert!");

     } else {
       // Extract planning time from the plan
       double planning_time = plan.planning_time_;

       // Publish planning time
       std_msgs::msg::Float64 planningTimeMsg;
       planningTimeMsg.data = planning_time;
       planningTimePub->publish(planningTimeMsg);

       std_msgs::msg::Float64 planningAttMsg;
       planningAttMsg.data = attempt+1;
       planningAttPub->publish(planningAttMsg);


       double total_distance = 0.0;
       for (size_t i = 1; i < plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points.size(); ++i)
       {
           total_distance += calculateDistance(plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points[i-1].positions, plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points[i].positions);
       }
     std_msgs::msg::Float64 planLengthMsg;
     planLengthMsg.data = total_distance;
     planLenPub->publish(planLengthMsg);

     }
   }

   std_msgs::msg::Bool planningResultMsg;
   planningResultMsg.data = success;
   planningResultPub->publish(planningResultMsg);
  
          
   // Wenn es einen Plan gibt ausführen
   if (success){

     double execution_duration = 0.0;
     auto execute_start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode result = move_group_interface.execute(plan);
     auto execute_end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     execution_duration = std::chrono::duration<double>(execute_end_time - execute_start_time).count();
           
     // Publish execution time
     std_msgs::msg::Float64 executionTimeMsg;
     executionTimeMsg.data = execution_duration;
     executionTimePub->publish(executionTimeMsg);

     if (result == moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS){
       RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("EndEffectorIkSolverNode"), "Geplante Bewegung ausgeführt");
     } else {
       RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("EndEffectorIkSolverNode"), "geplante Bewegung konnte nicht ausgeführt werden");
     }
     std_msgs::msg::Bool executionResultMsg;
     executionResultMsg.data = (result == moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);
     executionResultPub->publish(executionResultMsg);


   } else {
     RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("EndEffectorIkSolverNode"), "Planning failed!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! _"... unit of measuremnt of the distance variable ..."_ distance is represented in meters in ROS. Please read [this REP](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) for more information.

Comment: hi @ravi I know that distance in row is normally calculated in meters, but here I put in a vector of joint_trajectory_positions, an the out coming numbers aren't plausibel if they are in meters

Answer (score 1):

In a ros `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint` message, the `position` field specifies a joint rotation position. The units are radians. It's not clear that the author of the code you show understood this.

Comment: Thank you very much, i agree this is a very weird way to calculate a distance but at least now I understand what im working with.